# Breadcrumbs for category pages

Tags: templating, categories, navigation

I'm a Craft first-timer building a simple blog site. I want to include breadcrumbs at the top of each page like so:

> siteurl.com: [Blog]
>
> siteurl.com/category/example-category: [Blog > Example Category]
>
> siteurl.com/post/2015/entry-title: [Blog > Entry Title]

I've found this snippet which correctly outputs the breadcrumb for the entry permalink page:

```
<ul class="breadcrumbs">
    <li><a href="{{ siteUrl }}">Blog</a></li>
    {% if craft.request.segments %}
        {% for crumb in entry.getAncestors() %}
           <li>{{ crumb.getLink() }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        <li>{{ entry.title() }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
</ul>
```

But I also need something that will include a crumb for when the visitor is on a category page.

So far, my templates are structured like so:

```
templates/
 | index.html
 | _layout.html
 | posts/
    | index.html
    | category.html
    | _entry.html
```

Where the breadcrumb snippet is included in '_layout.html'.

In EE, I would just check my segments and use Low Seg2Cat to grab the category title. Is there an equivalent to this process in Craft? Or is it handled completely differently?

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

If your categories are only one level deep, you could hard-code the breadcrumbs into the category template:

```
{% block breadcrumb %}
  <ul class="breadcrumbs">
    <li><a href="{{ siteUrl }}">Blog</a></li>
    <li>{{ category.title }}</li>
  </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

In `_layout.html` you would have:

```
{% block breadcrumb %}
  <ul class="breadcrumbs">
    <li><a href="{{ siteUrl }}">Blog</a></li>
    {% if craft.request.segments %}
      {% for crumb in entry.getAncestors() %}
        <li>{{ crumb.getLink() }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
      <li>{{ entry.title() }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Haven't tried this myself, but I think it would work - the category template would override the layout.

Of course, if you have multiple levels of categories, the intermediate levels won't be included, so it's not an ideal solution.